# My jquery if else if statements arent working

Tags: jquery, date, if-statement, each

I'm trying to run an if else statement using jQuery. I believe I've followed the correct structure but the code isn't running.

I believe it has something to do with the nature of the statements, where the one overrides the other regardless of the if else statement I written.

The last else if statement works but the middle one doesn't?

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gdcx7/

See code below

```
 <body>
<div class="thumb-holder">
    <div class="post-title" data-date="Tuesday,14 December 2013" data-time="18:00">
        <img class="featured-thumb" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Richmedia/Image/FeaturedGame/crysis3_298x168.jpg?cb=1334583481" alt="tag test" style="width:250px;height:156px" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="thumb-holder">
    <div class="post-title" data-date="Tuesday,14 December 2012" data-time="18:00">
        <img class="featured-thumb" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Richmedia/Image/FeaturedGame/crysis3_298x168.jpg?cb=1334583481" alt="tag test" style="width:250px;height:156px" />
    </div>
</div>

<div calss="thumb-holder">
    <div class="post-title" data-date="Tuesday,14 December 2012" data-time="18:00">
        <img class="featured-thumb" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Richmedia/Image/FeaturedGame/crysis3_298x168.jpg?cb=1334583481" alt="tag test" style="width:250px;height:156px" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="thumb-holder">
    <div class="post-title" data-date="Thursday,27 February 2014" data-time="18:00">
        <img class="featured-thumb" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Richmedia/Image/FeaturedGame/crysis3_298x168.jpg?cb=1334583481" alt="tag test" style="width:250px;height:156px" />
    </div>
</div>


<div class="thumb-holder">
    <div class="post-title" data-date="Thursday,25 December 2014" data-time="18:00">
        <img class="featured-thumb" src="http://web-vassets.ea.com/Assets/Richmedia/Image/FeaturedGame/crysis3_298x168.jpg?cb=1334583481" alt="tag test" style="width:250px;height:156px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
   $('.post-title').each(function () {
     //1 day old
     if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
      $(this).css({
        opacity: 0.5,
        border: '2px solid blue'
      });
    } 

     //older than 7 days
    else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime() - (24 * 7) * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
    $(this).css({
        opacity: 0.5,
        border: '2px solid red'
     });
    }

    //7 days to go
    else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime() + (24 * 7) * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
     $(this).css({
        opacity: 0.5,
        border: '2px solid green'
     });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you do the least constraint first:

if it's in the past then
if less than 7 days then
if less than 7 days

Firs toff, note the last two condition are identical. As far as I understand, the last one is there for the future ? If so, change your test sign and turn it to >

All this said, you should reverse ifses and end up with:

if in the future then
//
else if in the last past 7 days then
//
then 
// older than 7 days)
end

Additional notes :
— please, store the date in a local variable to make code lisible and less power hungry;
— take now time first (for same reasons) plus, ech time you invoke getTime, the result changes by the time calls span in time (it's milliseconds, but…)

Comment: Hi there, dont quite follow you. 

_"if it's in the past then if less than 7 days then if less than 7 days"_


The code is to effect 1 day old then 7 day old and then future dates

Answer (score 0):

Use below condition in your if clause-

```
    if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime() && new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() > new Date().getTime() - (24 * 1) * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    {
       -----
    }
```

Rest is fine. This will check if the test time belongs to last 24hrs i.e. 1 day old. Otherwise your if condition is checking if the timestamp is less than now means any time before now.

Also last if condition could be-

```
   else if (new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() < new Date().getTime() + (24 * 7) * 60 * 60 * 1000 && new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime() > new Date().getTime()) 
   {
      ------
   }
```

i.e. If Test time is less than future 7 days & greater than current time.

Comment: Thanks, I did try these but I get the same exact effect - the one statement overrides the others - does it have something to do with having to past time stamps?